# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str' (tried everything)

Tags: python-3.x

```
def square():
  while True:
    try:
        a = input("Enter a number: ")
        a = int(a)
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter an integer and not a string...try again")
    c = a * a
    print (c)

 square()
```

Throwing an error "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter a value that can't be converted to an integer, your program still continues and tries to multiply string with string which causes the error.

You can keep asking for input until you get a value that can be convertible to an integer. If you get your desired value, you should break out from while loop and do the rest.

```
def square():
    while True:
        try:
            a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter an integer and not a string...try again")
    c = a * a
    print (c)

square()
```

Comment: I had used break earlier, but was still getting the error. Now I understand it was the indentation problem for the lines after the print(). Thanks for your help.